# MySQL Difference between BEGIN and START TRANSACTION

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, transaction, auto-commit

I'm using RDS Aurora (MySQL 5.6)

By default Auto Commit flag is enabled.
I have a transaction as follows

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO .....;// STATEMENT 1
INSERT INTO ......;//STATEMENT 2
COMMIT;
```

I'm expecting both the Inserts to be commited only when COMMIT is executed.
But Statement 1 is Commiting as soon as it got executed.

So I wanted to know What does BEGIN do here ??

I was assuming that BEGIN does the task of disabling Auto Commit , Can someone also explain the difference between BEGIN and START TRANSACTION as well.

Comment: `BEGIN` starts code block. It is not relative to transactions. The only purpose of a BEGIN-END block (in addition to code structuring) is to create an existence/visibility area for the structures defined in it (variables, handlers, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

The [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) has this to say:

> BEGIN and BEGIN WORK are supported as aliases of START TRANSACTION for initiating a transaction. START TRANSACTION is standard SQL syntax, is the recommended way to start an ad-hoc transaction, and permits modifiers that BEGIN does not.
>
> The BEGIN statement differs from the use of the BEGIN keyword that starts a BEGIN ... END compound statement. The latter does not begin a transaction. See [Section 13.6.1, “BEGIN ... END Compound Statement”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/begin-end.html).